# Mysqli error PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' PHP8 MySql 8 Ubuntu 20

Tags: ssh, mysql

I have seen a thousand of these b answered with reinstall Mysql. Did that. Even more say uncomment extension=mysqli. Did that in both the cli folder and the apache folder. Mods-available shows its there. trying to run a command from command line that should trigger cron jobs in a cron.php file from cli. I get --

**PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0**

I am at my wits end. Why wont it work?

Comment: You're correct that the problem is not with MySQL server. The problem is with the PHP driver for MySQL. In this case, I couldn't find `/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli` in the official Ubuntu repositories, so it looks like a third party package

Comment: I did a 3rd install of php 8.2 and it worked. Only uncommented mysqli in cli and it works. Still pretty much a mystery unless it's only uncommenting it in one place that's important. Which seems wrong.